# Accessing values with localStorage.getItem is returning old value even after being cleared

Tags: javascript, reactjs, local-storage

I am using localStorage to save values in my react app. I am finding that even after using localStorage.clear() or localStorage.removeItem('some_key'). The next time I use localStorage.getItem('some_key), the old value is being retrieved. It's only until I empty cache with a hard reload does it truly clear it out. Is there any way around this?
?

Comment: use localStorage.removeItem

Comment: Sorry wait I am using removeItem (not remove) but it's still return previous value

Comment: Have you found the reason for this?

Answer (score 1):

Can you add a snippet for the code? `localStorage` is not similar to `state`, changing or deleting items from `localStorage` will not re-render your app.
And you can debug it on Chrome dev tool, remove an item from localStorage and then try to access it.